# Bootstrap cards - text coming out of the cards

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I developed 4 bootstrap cards in 4 different columns. Within each of these cards, I created a new card that contains some type of information.

My problem is that the text comes out of the card when I reduce the screen size (responsive test). What is my problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks !

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/nr3UjwcvhZ)

```css
.cardsZone {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.myCards {
  background: #E7EAF180 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-deck .card {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.mysmallCcards {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(9px - 1px) calc(9px - 1px) 0 0;
}

.mycardHeader {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}

.imgDash {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.brandName {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4D4F5C;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.subtitledash {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  ;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4D4F5C;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.imgusersDash {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.usrDash {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4981C226;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4981C2;
}

.p1 {
  background: #EFF0F2 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #BCBCCB;
  padding: 3px 7px 3px 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.duracaoDash {
  background: #D9DAE2 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #BCBCCB;
}

.card-body {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="six" style="height: 75%;">
  <div class="card-deck cardsZone">
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x:hidden;">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To achive the below sort of wrapping move your `style="overflow-y: auto;"` from `class="card-body"` to `class="card mysmallCcards"`

[image: c]

2) If you would prefer the below this sort of wrapping then change `<span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>` from a `span` tag to a `p` tag and change the following:

```
.mysmallCcards{
 width: 100%;
 background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
 border-radius: 8px;
 border: none;
 margin-top: 20px;

 overflow-y: auto;
 /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

.brandName{
 text-align: left;
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 letter-spacing: 0;
 color: #4D4F5C;
 /*white-space: nowrap; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 line-height: 0px;*/
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, the text keeps coming out of the white card

Comment: Worked well ! Is there a way for the text to be stretched vertically, but when it doesn't fit all, stick with ...?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean sorry

Comment: The text when I reduce the screen, it is no longer on the same line and will overlap on the bottom line.
There is a way to always place it on the same horizontal line and when it shrinks, for example, Settings in ...

Answer (score 1):

**First** - text goes out of card, because card's `width` is auto and doesn't fit its content, which is wider.

**Second** - It is hard to understand what do you want to achieve. But you can stick to that strategy:

- remove all hardcoded `style="overflow-y: auto;"` from `divs` with class `card-body`
- add `overflow: auto;` to `.myCards` in `css`
- add

```
.myCards > .card-body {
  min-width: fit-content;
}
```

The result look in snippet in full screen mode and change size of screen

```css
.cardsZone {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.myCards {
  background: #E7EAF180 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.myCards > .card-body {
  min-width: fit-content;
}

.card-deck .card {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.mysmallCcards {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(9px - 1px) calc(9px - 1px) 0 0;
}

.mycardHeader {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}

.imgDash {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.brandName {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4D4F5C;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.subtitledash {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  ;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4D4F5C;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.imgusersDash {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.usrDash {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4981C226;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4981C2;
}

.p1 {
  background: #EFF0F2 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #BCBCCB;
  padding: 3px 7px 3px 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.duracaoDash {
  background: #D9DAE2 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #BCBCCB;
}

.card-body {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="six" style="height: 75%;">
  <div class="card-deck cardsZone">
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

When you want a responsiveness, you have to decide, what do you mean, what it is for you.

Now I see, that your `html` structure is quite messy and I suggest to look it over. For example nested bootstrap cards not the best idea. And those questionable places a lot.

Quick fix, I would say a hack, just to see how it may look:

- remove overflow: auto; from `css` class `myCards`
- add `min-width: auto !important;` to `css` class `myCards`
- and can removw also

```
.myCards > .card-body {
  min-width: fit-content;
}
```

Check the snippet below, but look over your structure.

```css
.cardsZone {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.myCards {
  background: #E7EAF180 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: auto !important;
}

.card-deck .card {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.mysmallCcards {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(9px - 1px) calc(9px - 1px) 0 0;
}

.mycardHeader {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}

.imgDash {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.brandName {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4D4F5C;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.subtitledash {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  ;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4D4F5C;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.imgusersDash {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.usrDash {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4981C226;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4981C2;
}

.p1 {
  background: #EFF0F2 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #BCBCCB;
  padding: 3px 7px 3px 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.duracaoDash {
  background: #D9DAE2 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #BCBCCB;
}

.card-body {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="six" style="height: 75%;">
  <div class="card-deck cardsZone">
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">
            <div class="card-header mycardHeader">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgDash">
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="brandName card-title card-text">Settings in the world</span>
                  <p class="subtitledash card-subtitle card-text">Test Settings</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GSwsSV5GzGFyheupOV4x6deWq7yekyqbpOF_wp5wrfhCNjiDYu1pxYTbYNTip-e6Xi0" class="img-responsive imgusersDash">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="p-2">
                  <span class="p1">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2"> <span class="duracaoDash">00:00:00</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to make this responsive without using overflow-x?